# Run-time error - type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which adds specific vales to specific strings. However I am currently getting a runtime error, which I can not figure out why?

```
Case "L"

    If UCase(Left(Dn, 3)) = "L/M" Then
        Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 4, 2)) + 35

    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 2)) = "LM" Then
        'Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 3, 3)) + 3.5
        If IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 3, 1)) And IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 4, 1)) Then
            If Mid(Dn, 4, 1) = "0" Then
                Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 3, 2) + 3.5
            Else
                Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 3, 2) + 0.35
            End If
        End If

        If IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 4, 1)) And IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 5, 1)) Then
            If Mid(Dn, 5, 1) = "0" Then
                Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 3, 3) + 35
            Else
                Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 3, 3) + 0.35
            End If
        End If

    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 3)) = "LOW" Then
        Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 4, 2)) + 20
    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 3)) = "LO-" Then
        Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 4, 2)) + 20
    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 6)) = "LO MID" Then
        Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 7, 3)) + 35
    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 2)) = "L+" Then
        Dn.Offset(, 1) = Num
    ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 3)) = "LO " Then
        Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 4, 2)) + 20


        'ElseIf UCase(Left(Dn, 1)) = "L" Then
        'Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 2, 3)) + 2
        'ElseIf IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 2, 1)) Then
        'Dn.Offset(, 1) = IIf(IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 2, 1) + Mid(Dn, 3, 1)), Val(Mid(Dn, 2, 3)) + 2, Val(Mid(Dn, 2, 1)) + 0.2)

    ElseIf IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 2, 1)) And IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 3, 1)) Then
        If Mid(Dn, 3, 1) = "0" Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 2) + 2
        Else
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 2) + 0.2
        End If
    Else
        Dn.Offset(, 1) = Val(Mid(Dn, 2, 3)) + 20
    End If
    If IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 3, 1)) And IsNumeric(Mid(Dn, 4, 1)) Then
        If Mid(Dn, 4, 1) = "0" Then
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 3) + 20
        Else
            Dn.Offset(, 1) = Mid(Dn, 2, 3) + 0.2
        End If

    End If
```

Input data

```
*vh105 --> 105.9
*h107 --> 107.8
*l107 --> 107.2
*lm106 --> 106.35
*lm106  
*l107   
*44
```

Any help with this problem would be very much be appreciated.

Comment: use the step into (Debug > Step Into) to debug and see which line of your code it actually stops working. Also open the locals watch window (View > Locals Watch) to see if all values are according to your expectations

Comment: thank you so much for your response, but there is problem with the 3rd line code.  Also, my local watch variable does not show anything.  I have the same code for, Case M, with same code for "MH" and M variables and I so not get any mistype errors when running those.

Comment: locals watch will show the values or object assignment for local elements. So I would expect Dn to be shown there as it looks to me as it is a local variable of the type `string`.

Comment: I am also wondering from your input data set how the code would actually end up in the 3rd line of code (The `If` statement should be false thus the code would skip to the `ElseIf`

Answer (score 0):

Isolate the `Val(Mid(Dn,4,2))` or even the `Mid(Dn,4,2)` as I think the Val doesnt get a proper numerical string to work with from the `Mid` function

Use this between line 2 and 3:

> `Debug.Print Mid(Dn,4,2)
>
>     Debug.Print Val(Mid(Dn,4,2))`

Let us know what you get in the Immediate Window (if not present go to View > Immediate Window)

Comment: you should include what he should type in the immediate window as he may not know.

Comment: there is nothing to type in the window, the debug.print in the code will print in the immediate window...